# Android Bluetooth Multiple Master/Slave connections

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, master-slave

I need a confirmation on how Android Bluetooth Master/Slave connections work. As I understand a Master can serve up to 7 Slaves as long as they are on different UUIDs? Can a Slave be client to multiple Masters if the Masters have different UUIDs or can they all have the same UUID? I would appreciate if you point me to any documentation that states this clearly or any one could share some experiences?